Reverse Polarity Circuit Protection
I have an adjustable voltage battery charger that goes from 6v to 14.8v and I need a reverse polarity protection to substitute the old one, which doesn't work. I mounted a circuit based on the following Analog Devices application note but it's not working as described.
It is supposed to work when connecting a reversed polarity battery with the charger turned off AND when it's turned on and already running. However, it only works at the first case and analyzing it, I think that's what is expected.
When the charger is running, the out- terminal is at the same potential as ground and the pnp mosfet shouldn't detect the reversed battery. But that is opposite of what's saying at the application note, in which it even describes a test at that situation working fine.
What am I doing wrong and what can I do to solve this?


Analog Device's Application Note
Edit1: I realized this circuit is too dependent on the internal resistance of the batteries and mosfet. So I changed it to another one, shown below. On the simulation, it works in all scenarios, but when testing it, it only works when the battery is reversely connected when the charger initial state is off.
Edit2: The issue is again, on the internal resistances. A discharged battery, lead acid has high impedance. Sometimes, 1 Ohm. Considering that the used mosfet has Rds(on)=2.4mOhm, the voltage drop prior to the resistor and diode results in insufficient voltage/current to disengage the bjt.


There would be a dramatic current peak if the charger is active, but there is a chance, that MN1 will be off in time. Did you simulate or test it?

Yes. the test didn't work when the charger was already running. On simulation, when considering the internal resistances, it doesn't work too.
